# CTAD rules regarding implicit deduction guides

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, ctad

I would expect the construction of `b` as in `b{d{}}` to result in a compilation error, as `b`'s templated constructor is not viable due to its constraints. However, GCC and MSVC seem to accept this code and deduce `b` to be `b<int>` instead of `b<d>`. Which seems odd, as I don't see how `b`'s implicit deduction guide would be much different from `template<typename T> b(T) -> b<T>;`.

Which compiler can we trust this time? What does the C++20 standard have to say about this behavior?

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct b {
    b() = default;
    b(T) requires false {}
};
struct d : b<int> {};
inline constexpr auto z = b{d{}};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TaPocj94n)

---

Clang's error message:

```cpp
<source>:7:27: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'b<d>'
    7 | inline constexpr auto z = b{d{}};
      |                           ^~~~~~
<source>:2:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor)
not viable: no known conversion from 'd' to 'const b<d>' for 1st argument
    2 | struct b {
      |        ^
<source>:2:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor)
not viable: no known conversion from 'd' to 'b<d>' for 1st argument
    2 | struct b {
      |        ^
<source>:4:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: constraints not satisfied
    4 |     b(T) requires false {}
      |     ^
<source>:4:19: note: because 'false' evaluated to false
    4 |     b(T) requires false {}
      |                   ^
<source>:3:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments,
but 1 was provided
    3 |     b() = default;
      |     ^
```

Comment: Would generated CTAD be `template<typename T> b(T) -> b<T> requires false;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver `requires false` is just a simplified example. The same result can be observed when changing it to something like: `requires std::same_as<T, T[]>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I could see how the implicit guide would simply take over the entire template head, which includes the requires-clause. Not sure how this ends up with `b<int>` instead of `b<d>`, however.

Comment: @303: Whereas users cannot use trailing requires-clauses, isn't the implicit created one can use it? (It is what I understand from first C++20 bullet of [Implicitly-generated deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#Deduction_for_class_templates))

Comment: CTAD from copy constructor, as `d` is a `b<int>`.

Comment: Interestingly, GCC deduces that the type of `z` is `b<int>`. https://godbolt.org/z/7o5nKMreh . Whether a bug or not, it looks like the simple rule `template<typename T> b(T) -> b<T>;` doesn't apply. At least in the case that `T` is related to the `b` template.

Comment: @NathanOliver, what do you mean `requires false` is ill-formed. Does it need to depend on an template parameters?  Like `requires (sizeof(T) == 0)` ?

Comment: If you add the trivial CTAD rule `template<class T> b(T) -> b<T>;` all the compilers behave consistently, https://godbolt.org/z/GEGY767YT

Comment: @alfC I removed my comment as in this case I do not think I was remembering correctly and I can't find anything to back it up.

Comment: @NathanOliver, related https://stackoverflow.com/q/77923182/225186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 5 implicit deduction guides for class template argument deduction in this case. The first two are generated from declared constructors:

- `template <typename T> b() -> b<T>;` (can never be used, since `T` is not deducible)
- `template <typename T> b(T) requires false -> b<T>;` (associated constraints never satisfied)

Then there are two generated from the implicit copy constructor and implicit move constructor:

- `template <typename T> b(const b<T>&) -> b<T>;`
- `template <typename T> b(b<T>&&) -> b<T>;`

Finally, during class template argument deduction, there is always an implicit *copy deduction candidate* as described in [[over.match.class.deduct]/1.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1.3):

> An additional function template derived as above from a hypothetical constructor `C(C)`, called the *copy deduction candidate*.

This implicit deduction guide, which behaves like `template <typename T> b(b<T>) -> b<T>`, is separate from the one generated from the actual copy constructor.

In the case of `b{d{}}`, deduction succeeds for the last three deduction guides, with `T` being deduced as the type such that `b<T>` is a base class of `D`, namely, `int`. The implicit deduction guide from the move constructor wins over the one from the copy constructor (because the argument is an rvalue) but the copy deduction candidate wins over both of them thanks to the tiebreaker rule in [[over.match.best.general]/2.12](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best.general#2.12):

> ... a viable function `F`<sub>1</sub> is defined to be a *better* function than another viable function `F`<sub>2</sub> if...
>
> - [...]
> - `F1` is the copy deduction candidate and `F2` is not, ...
> - [...]

CTAD succeeds and deduces `b<int>`. A second overload resolution is then done to perform the actual initialization `b<int>{d{}}`. For the actual initialization, the copy deduction candidate doesn't exist. The move constructor is called.

Clang presumably just has some bug here.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the *copy deduction candidate* and the subtle interference it has in situations as such. It seems to explain the unexpected behavior pretty well. However, it is rather surprising that this leads us to conclude that Clang completely overlooked this rule.

Comment: @303 I don't think Clang necessarily overlooked that particular rule; they might just have a subtle bug somewhere.